Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus
When I normally open/close the popup the aria-hidden was not showing. but if i open the popup inspect the inside of the modal element then I close it the error was showing. how to solve this problem. I was using the bootstrap 4.
Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus. The focus must not be hidden from assistive technology users. Avoid using aria-hidden on a focused element or its ancestor. Consider using the inert attribute instead, which will also prevent focus. For more details, see the aria-hidden section of the WAI-ARIA specification at https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-hidden.
Element with focus: button

Hello. The question still needs some clarifications, would be great if you could add answers to it: Where does this error message come from? Is it Lighthouse? What do you mean with “normally” opening the pop-up? Are you using the built-in data-toggle="modal" attributes along with Bootstrap’s JavaScript, or another method or library? Bootstrap itself correctly sets focus to the triggering element when closing it, whether or not you inspect the dialog., I just verified on the modal demo page.

Best is always to provide an example in an interactive code snippet in the question.

Hello @Andy,
I created a Bootstrap 4 modal popup, and I noticed an issue in the console. If I inspect elements within the popup, such as the modal-header or modal-body, and then attempt to close the popup, an error appears in the console. This only happens when inspecting elements inside the popup; otherwise, the error does not occur. I also checked the Bootstrap official website, and the same issue is present there.

So the only thing you are doing is clicking on “Launch demo modal” and then on “Close”, while the console is open? Which browser and version are you using? I can’t reproduce it this way with Firefox or Chromium.
